# SPSS Selecting cases (outliers) seperately for each split file

Tags: regression

I divided my dataset in 10 groups (because I have 10 different industries). Now, in SPSS one can use "select cases" to get rid of outliers.This is fine. However, I want to apply a different "select cases" rule for each of the 10 groups because it would be wrong to just set the same threshold value for each industry. Does anybody know how to do it?

Many thanks for your help guys!

Cheerz
Steven

Comment: Sorry I am probably not well versed enough in SPSS to give any good advice, maybe you can find some forum or tutorial at their homepage. In general finding outliers is not a very easy problem and there exist very many different ways to try and do it. Maybe they are just lone travellers on a random walk or searching for liberty or cookies or beer.